# Check if variable contains any value of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays like so;

```
arr1 = ["foo.com", "bar.com"],
arr2 = ["//test.net/index.html", "http://www.bar.com", "https://foo.com/example.js"]
```

I'm iterating through `arr2` and I want to omit the ones that contain any value of `arr1`.

Currently I'm using `indexOf` but that doesn't work if the values don't match exactly.

```
$.each(arr2, function(k,v){
  if(arr1.indexOf(v) == -1)
    console.log(v);
});
```

I'd hope for the above code to output

```
//test.net/index.html
```

since it's the only value of `arr2` that doesn't *contain* any value of `arr1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: test is backwards, all of the `arr1` strings are shorter than `arr2` strings so they will never contain them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrote two each loops for this:

```js
arr1 = ["foo.com", "bar.com"],
arr2 = ["//test.net/index.html", "http://www.bar.com", "https://foo.com/example.js"]

$.each(arr2, function(x,y){
    var found = false;
    $.each(arr1, function(k,v){
        if(!(y.indexOf(v) == -1)){
        found = true;
        return false;
        }
    });
    
    if(!found){
        console.log(y);
    }
    
    found= false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However it would be more optimal to use `for` loop and `break` to stop the search once occurrence is found. Or to return `false` from `$.each` to break the loop.

Comment: Yes thats true, i changed the code to return false after founding.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) ES5 Array methods:

```js
var arr1 = ["foo.com", "bar.com"],
    arr2 = ["//test.net/index.html", "http://www.bar.com", "https://foo.com/example.js"];

var result = arr2.filter(function(val) {
    return !arr1.some(function(el) {
        return val.indexOf(el) !== -1;
    });
});

alert(result);
```

Support for ES5 starts from IE9+, but if you need it to work in older IE, you can use polyfills (see links I provided), or it's pretty trivial to rewrite `some` part with simple `for` loop and use `$.grep` instead of `Array.prototyp.filter`.

Comment: *filter* is also an ES5 method. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Yes, just like I said `filter` and `some` methods :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems That you're using the Array version of indexOf, which doesn't work id the match is not exact.
With a little bit more setup, you can use the String version of indexOf

```
function compareValues (arr1, arr2){

var res = false;
$.each(arr2, function(k,v) {
    checkAgainstArray(arr1, v);
});

function checkAgainstArray(arr1, value) {
    $.each(arr1, function(k, v) {
       if(value.indexOf(v) !== -1){
         res  = true;
       }
    });
}
  return res;
}
```

//later on

var isValueInArray = compareValues(arr1, arr2);

(the code is not tested), but I Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Try use the javascript RegExp to do the matching for each array element

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp